# Apache only showing contents of /var/www/html but no any other websites (error 403)

Tags: docker, apache, ubuntu

I have installed PHP+Apache in my Docker Ubuntu container, but I have a problem:

When I define no website in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and I access my site `docker2.mysite.com/info.php`, I see the contents of .php file being executed well, but when I add a `docker2.conf` in that path and run `a2ensite site` then reloading apache, I get error 403.

It seems the issue is the files in `/var/www/html/` are executed, while other sites are not running.

Here is `docker2.conf` contents:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName docker2.mysite.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@docker2
        DocumentRoot /home/docker2
        <Directory />
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried `chown`ing `DocumentRoot` to `www-data` but it does not change.

A couple of days ago I have done this and the site was executing from its own path, but I don't know what's the issue it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default your apache acl denies from all for your hole system, and allowes form /var/www/html

add an `allow from all`  or a `require all granted` depending on your version.

```
        <Directory /home/docker2>
            DirectoryIndex index.html
            Require all Granted
        </Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the argument `all` should be in lower case. I just mentioned so that if anyone will read your answer in the future, checks the right answer.